# Heroku Python app with custom package in Aptfile : no python packages installed from requirements.txt

Tags: python, heroku, pip, apt, requirements.txt

I'm attempting to install a package and I was pointed in the direction of installing heroku-buildpack-apt and heroku-buildpack-multi. This seems to work and now the project builds on the remote and I have installed multi using:

```
heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
```

and installed the apt-get via including its reference in a `.buildpacks` file https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-apt

Now put the packages in `Aptfile` which is:

```
libgeoip-dev
```

The remote now builds, but I I get complains about not finding `gunicorn`, which I assume is some kind of conflict because it is listed in `requirements.txt` Does the `Aptfile` override requirements?

Comment: Seems like you should include the `heroku/python` buildpack, as that's what causes requirements.txt dependencies to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

Add `heroku/python` to your buildpacks run

```
heroku buildpacks:clear # to clear previous configs
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku-community/apt # to enable heroku build packages in Aptfile
heroku buildpacks:add --index 2 heroku/python # to install python libs in requirement.txt
```

Should build both in your next push